# Why I can't I find the file in my android phone directory, even when my app says it exists?

Tags: java, android-studio

```
        File file = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(), "folder");

        if(!file.exists())
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "file dont exists creating one in: " + file.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            file.mkdir();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "file exists in: " + file.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

         try {
             if(file.exists()) {
                 File myObj = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "filename.txt");
                 if (myObj.createNewFile()) {
                     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, myObj.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                 } else {
                     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File already exists in: " + myObj.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                 }
             }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"e: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

So this is my code, when I run it, it creates a folder, in that folder there is a file called filename.txt, but when I search for it on my android phone file manager, I can't find it why?

Comment: When you call `getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()`, it returns the internal storage directory specific to your app, which is not accessible through the file manager on your Android device.